# QGLWidget appears black in Windows 7

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qglwidget

I wrote and tested some code in a Windows XP (Qt 4.7.2) using Visual Studio 2010 and then I tried on another machine with Windows 7 installed.

The program opens a QDialog and creates a QGLWidget where I show webcam images (with some processing). While in Windows XP the images are shown correctly, at the moment that I test the program in a Windows 7 machine, the QGLWidget turns black and no image is shown. It is strange, though, that when I move around the window and it gets out of the borders of the screen, the image is shown for an instant and pitch black when I stop moving again, which makes me think that the images are correctly received/processed (some times), and that it might be a problem with a QTimer.

The relevant code is:

Initialization:

```
void GLVideo::initializeGL()
{   
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glClearDepth(1.0f);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);

    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);

    // Some OpenCV processing

    // Here I declare the timer, might it be the problem?
    m_timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect( m_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(timeOutSlot()) );
    m_timer->start( 33 );

}
```

Slot that is called every timeout:

```
void GLVideo::timeOutSlot() 
{
    ReceiveInfo();
    LoadTextures();
}

void GLVideo::LoadTextures() 
{   
    // Get the image from the webcam
    ProcessCamera();

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);  
    glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, qImage->width(), 
        qImage->height(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, qImage->bits());
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );

    updateGL();
}

void GLVideo::resizeGL( int width, int height )
{
    height = height?height:1;
    glViewport( 0, 0, (GLint)width, (GLint)height );
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45.0f,(GLfloat)width/(GLfloat)height,0.1f,100.0f);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}
```

And finally, the paint function of the Widget:

```
void GLVideo::paintGL()
{   
    glPushAttrib(GL_ALL_ATTRIB_BITS) ;
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

    glPopAttrib() ;

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    glColor4f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f, 1.0f);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(-1.65f, 1.24f, -3.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f( 1.65f, 1.24f, -3.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f( 1.65f,-1.24f, -3.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.65f,-1.24f, -3.0f);
    glEnd();    

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPopMatrix();

    // Some 2D drawing:
}
```

Any idea on what am I doing wrong? Might it be the QTimer that is not calling the SLOT timeOutSlot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your program works in Windows XP but not in Windows 7, I recommend that you should check if there is a newer version of the display driver.

Comment: The truth is that as the images were shown "sometimes" I didn't think it was a problem of the drivers but... it was. Updating to the last version made the program work with no problem in Windows 7. Thanks!

Comment: I am having the same issue. My graphics driver is Nvidia GEforce 8400GS. If I try to update it from Device manager, I get the message that the driver is up-to-date. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: I had the same problem. Device Manager said that the driver was updated, so I tried silvermaci solution above. It didn't worked, so I downloaded a new driver installer, installed it, and then it fixed the problem. 
Don't thrust the Device Manager on things like this. Check drivers versions at the vendor website.

Answer (score 5):

You're using OpenGL API outside of `paintGL()`, `resizeGL()`, or `initializeGL()`.

When your slot is called, modify any state to be able to draw the new frame, *but don't call OpenGL API yet*. Instead, call `QWidget::updateGL()`, and do the OpenGL calls in your reimplementation of `paintGL()`.

The problem you're experiencing is that, outside these three functions, your GL context isn't the current one. On older OSs, that might not be a problem, but any OS with a compositing window manager will make problems. E.g., in your case, your program may have been the only OpenGL user under XP, so yours was always the current context. But in Windows 7, the desktop itself uses, if not OpenGL, then Direct3D, ie. the same hardware.

If you absolutely *must* call OpenGL function outside those three functions, you need to call `QGLWidget::makeCurrent()` first, but note that this is not idiomatic use.

Regarding the `QTimer` creation in `initializeGL()`: it's certainly more idiomatic to create that timer in the class' constructor, but it should be ok in `initializeGL()`, too.

Comment: Hi mmutz, You're right on the OpenGL calls outside of the functions that you mention. I modified the code (now there is only OpenGL code inside of the paintGL(), resizeGL(), initializaGL() functions). I am still having the same problem, though. The OpenGL Widget is black and only shows an image when I partially move the windows outside of the limit of the screen.

Comment: Just to be sure, I have a "draw" function that's called from paintGL. In that function it calls out all other OpenGL functions. This shouldn't be a problem, right?

Answer (score 3):

Hi I had a similar problem (black screen with intermittently correctly drawn image) with new NVIDIA drivers (280.something) + Win7, I fixed the problem by removing the manual swapBuffers call at the end of my paintGL and in the constructor setting setAutoBufferSwap(true) - hope this helps.