# QGLWidget appears black in Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: windows, qt, opengl

My Qt app is working fine on Win7 32 bit but on Win7 64 bit QGLWidget appears black.
If I shake the application window, it appears for a sec and again it is blank.

Same issue was reported ([QGLWidget appears black in Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901884/qglwidget-appears-black-in-windows-7/5902792)) which resolved after the user updated graphics driver.

I have NVIDIA GEFORCE 8500 driver and updated it to the latest from NVIDIA site, but still see the same issue.

On Win7 32 bit I don't see any graphics issue.

I have built Qt and my application on Win XP 64 bit.
Do I need to build Qt and/or my application on Win7 64 bit?

UPDATE:
I built a brand new machine with Intel i5 processor and equivalent motherboard.
Without installing the nVidia graphics card, I don't see blackening of opengl window.
But if I install the nVidia graphics card I start seeing the black opengl window.
Also this balckening is not observed in a simple opengl window application I created. It only happens with QGLWidget.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should try is to download the binary version from Qt website, that should run without problems in all supported Windows versions.
If it doesn't work, then you can try to rebuild your Qt on Win7.

Comment: Thanks Riccardo. I am downloading the pre-built libraries from Qt.

Comment: Using qt pre-built libraries don't work. But if I disable the graphics driver using Device manager I don't see any black window.